# Template argument: pointer to member - what should I do with it?

Tags: c++, templates

The C++ draft says that

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following
>   (optionally cv-qualified) types: — integral or enumeration type, —
>   pointer to object or pointer to function, — lvalue reference to object
>   or lvalue reference to function, — **pointer to member**, —
>   std::nullptr_t.

In the following code I have a pointer to member passed as parameter to a template

```
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:

    int membervar;
};


template< int (MyClass::*var) > struct A 
{
   // What am I supposed to do with *var? There isn't an object instance to use it!
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   struct A <&MyClass::membervar> object;

}
```

The above code compiles (MSVC2012) without errors

The question is: I don't see what am I supposed to do with such a pointer, there isn't an object instance to use it

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this!  If you want to use a pointer-to-member, then you need an object.  It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to answer this is to construct an example:

```
template< int (MyClass::*var) > struct A 
{
    A() {
        MyClass myclass;
        myclass.*var = 42;
        cout << myclass.*var << "\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you I learned something with the pointers-to-member variables and functions today!

Answer (score 1):

You use it as a regular **[pointer-to-member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx)**:

```
template< int (MyClass::*var) > struct A 
{
   void foo()
   {
      MyClass Blah;
      Blah.*var = 3;
   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I learned something new today!!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents `A` from having methods taking `MyClass` as parameters though:

```
template <int (MyClass::*var)>
struct A {
    int get(MyClass const& mc) const { return mc.*var; }
    void set(MyClass& mc, int i) { mc.*var = i; }
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;

    A<&MyClass::membervar> a;

    a.set(mc, 3);
    std::cout << a.get(mc) << "\n"; // prints 3
}
```